# Add Java compiler to Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab

When i typed mbuild-setup in matlab(r2011a), there was no java compiler (jdk) available there, although i already installed jdk 1.7 on my computer.

So, how could i add java compiler to matlab (mbuild-setup)?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable? That might be how Matlab detects the JDK location, and IIRC, the JDK installer does not set it by default.

Comment: Did your problem get resolve? If you can explain how it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see only JDK 1.6 is supported. See http://www.mathworks.de/support/compilers/R2011b/win32.html

Comment: After having uninstalled jdk 1.7, the same errors happened to me (although java version in window is now 1.6...).

Comment: hmmm strange. Maybe make sure you install jdk 1.6. maybe reastart Matlab - or reboot. If all that doesn't help you will need to contact their support.